# Code works in Dockerfile but not in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, dockerfile

I have to docker procedures:

1. First one uses a Dockerfile and does `docker build -t d1 .` and then `docker run -p 4022:22 d1`
2. Second one uses a docker-compose.yml file, launched by command `docker-compose up`

First one works, no error, second one fails, the command ansible-galaxy which does https git operations never happens, but shows no error.
Any idea?

The Dockerfile contents:

```
FROM myregistry.org/ansible-rhel:admin

COPY . /home/ansible/playbook-ldap-myapp
WORKDIR /home/ansible/playbook-ldap-myapp
USER ansible
RUN ansible-galaxy install -fr requirements.yml --roles-path roles/
```

The docker-compose.yml contents:

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  public: {}

volumes:
  playbook:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: $PWD

services:
  ansible-admin:
    image: myregistry.org/ansible-rhel:admin
    ports:
      - '4022:22'
    networks:
      - public
    volumes:
      - playbook:/home/ansible/playbook-ldap-myapp
    working_dir: /home/ansible/playbook-ldap-myapp
    user: ansible
    command: ''
    command: 'ansible-galaxy install -fr requirements.yml --roles-path roles/'
```

Comment: Are you tried with different service name?

Comment: The two `command:` lines might be related to your issue; try deleting the empty one.  Your `volumes:` mount is hiding everything in that directory, and your Dockerfile basically has no effect at all (I'd prefer the Dockerfile path).  You might find it easier to run Ansible in a non-Docker Python virtual environment than trying to shoehorn it into Docker like this.

Comment: Deleting the empty command worked, thanks a lot

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm not sure what you mean by non Docker Python env. I'm an ansible noob, I just wrote 2 roles, tested with molecule, this is my first playbook. The task I'm assigned to is testing a playbook on a bunch of servers that are (almost) identical to production ones, meaning one ansible admin, 2 ansible targets, one ldap client. How can I achieve that without Docker? I'm trying to build those servers in a docker compose file that would run the whole system. If you know another solution to run it without Docker, I'm interested.

Comment: There's pretty extensive documentation on https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/.  On your local system you can just install Ansible, without needing Docker.  There are Ansible tasks (_modules_) that can manage the Docker containers or launch `docker-compose` on the remote systems.  The only requirements really are that you can make outbound connections from the local system to the hosts you're managing, and that the remote systems have Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your docker-compose.yml you have two `command:` entries:

```
    command: ''
    command: 'ansible-galaxy install -fr requirements.yml --roles-path roles/'
```

Per the Docker Compose file version 3 reference at: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

The `command:` attribute overrides the default executable that runs within your specified entrypoint, at run time.

There can only be one `command`, and the first `command` you have specified ostensibly causes additional `command` entries to be ignored.

Remove the `command: ''` line and your Ansible command should run. However it will be the only thing that runs.